# neo4j 2 start failes after workings well

Tags: neo4j

my neo4j server workings well, but my server restarted and neo4j not started

server : Ubuntu 13.10
jdk: oracle jdk

this is errors:

```
SEVERE: 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:209)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:333)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:319)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:144)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@4b9de054' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:310)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@5df0330b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@3fc9dd8c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:411)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:324)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:236)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:301)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:224)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 20 more

Jan 20, 2014 1:02:28 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Comment: Is this Neo4j 2.0.0 Final ?

Comment: Would you be able to share your database with us for checking? Please drop me an email at michael at neotechnology.com

Comment: this db is for test and i remove my graph.db folder from neo4j lib and now i think this is a clean db created by neo4j startup

Comment: @MichaelHunger i download neo4j-community-1.8.3-unix.tar.gz and run it, its works fine, wtf?

Comment: have a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985168/error-using-neo4j-with-jdk-1-7
(worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I was previously facing this problem. Later I figured out few points that you need to make sure are properly handled.

1. Make sure to use one instance at a time if in embedded mode.
2. Register shutdown hook properly
3. See if the server is still not running indexing while you restart.
4. delete tm_tx_log.1 file from the neo4j-db folder and then restart.

Now first 3 are less probable causing your problem, so what I did that I caught the exception thrown then deleted the tm_tx_log.1 file and then initialized the service. Not fool proof but a work around.

```
     public class GraphDB {



        private static GraphDB graph = null;
        private static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-db";
        private static GraphDatabaseService graphService = null;

        protected GraphDB() {
            try{
            graphService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
            registerShutdownHook(graphService);
            }catch(Exception e){
                File file = new File(DB_PATH+"/tm_tx_log.1");
                file.delete();
            }
        }

        public static GraphDB getInstance() {
            if (graph == null) {
                graph = new GraphDB();
            }
            return graph;
        }

        public GraphDatabaseService getGraphDbService() {
            return graphService;

        }

        public void clearDb() {
            try {
                // FileUtils.deleteRecursively();
                File files = new File(DB_PATH);
                for(File file : files.listFiles()){
                    FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public void shutDown() {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Shutting down database ...");
            graphService.shutdown();
        }

        private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    graphDb.shutdown();
                }
            });
        }    
        }
```

And in your main section while calling handle the case when the graphService is null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphDB graphDb = GraphDB.getInstance();
        if(graphDb == null){
            graphDb = GraphDB.getInstance();
        }
}
```